# How to display in a jquery script in a main page slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Lately I try to make a script which grab news from my facebook wall and post on my website.
With some research and some edit resulted this: [example](http://aepado.ro/reindex.html)

Now, I want to put this script in the middle slider of [this page](http://www.aepado.ro/en/)

Connections are all right (js/css/script), but doesn't appear.

This is the sequence of slider part: (In slider are displayed also news manually introduced in database.)

```
 <div id="middle_article">
    <div class="jcarousel-prev-vertical" style="left:63px;"></div>
    <div class="jcarousel-next-vertical" style="left:63px;"></div>
    <ul id="stiri" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <?php 
            $result_other_news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stiri` WHERE `status` = '1' AND `lang` = 'ro' ORDER BY `data` DESC LIMIT 1,10");
            while($row_other_news = mysql_fetch_array($result_other_news)){
                $link_stire = 'http://www.aepado.ro/stiri/'.friendly_url($row_other_news['titlu']).'-'.$row_other_news['id'].'.html';
        ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $link_stire; ?>"><?php echo substr($row_other_news['titlu'], 0, 75); ?></a>
            </li>

        <?php } ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Head part of my index page (correspondence with my problem):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="http://aepado.ro/css/jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.css" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://aepado.ro/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://aepado.ro/js/jquery.neosmart.fb.wall.js" type="text/javascript">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function(){
$('#example1').fbWall({ id:'***',accessToken:'***'});
});
</script>
```

And, this is sequence to display script:

```
<div id="example1"></div>
```

Finally, i will thank you in advance, and if you need some more information i will gave you with pleasure.

Best regards,
Cosmin

Comment: You might want to put the javascript at the bottom of the <body> tag or add the a "$(" in front of the function  - $(function(){ $('#example1').fbWall({ id:'***',accessToken:'***'});
});
Also the current script has a closing ")" what is that there for? what bracket is it closing?

Comment: Thank you for response. That closing ")" it was a mistake, i fix that. I will try your suggestion, and I post here the results.

Answer (score 0):

did you initialize jcarousel?

```
$(function(){
('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
});
```